# Are there any code which just derivative of piecewise function(same distence)?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, output-formatting, piecewise

I wrote this code:

```
Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, x <= 4}}]
```

and I got its derivative with this code:

```
D[Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, x <= 4}}], x]
```

But I need derivative just of function, and same distance, i.e.

[image: Output]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MapAt[D[#, x] &, Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, x <= 4}}], {{1, ;; , 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Note:** this function works for expressions with `Head` `Piecewise`. For general expressions that contain `Piecewise` subexpressions, it can be used with `ReplaceAll` as follows:

```
Y[x_] = Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, x <= 4}}]*F + 
   Piecewise[{{x^4, 0 <= x <= 3}, {x, x <= 6}}]*G;

Y[x] /. pw_Piecewise :> MapAt[D[#, {x, 2}] &, pw, {{1, ;; , 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I need the same output in picture. For 0<=x<=1, (2x)

Comment: @ kglr If possible for you which describe about  {1, ;; , 1}. And If I have Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, 1 <= x <= 4}, {x, 4 <= x <= 5}}] this code is correct, too.

Comment: @bahram, `{{i,j,k}}` refers to  the part `{i,j,k}`, i.e.,  "the _k_ th part of the _ j_ th part of _i_ th part" of the object in the second argument of `MapAt`.  `;;` is the same as `All`. For `pw= Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, x <= 4}}]`, you can inspect `pw[[1]]`, `pw[[1,2]]`, `pw[[1, 2,1]]`, `pw[[1, ;;,1]]` or `pw[[1,All,1]]` etc to see the parts.  Replacing the second argument in `MapAt`  with `Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, 1 <= x <= 4}, {x, 4 <= x <= 5}}] ` you should get a similar result.

Comment: @ kglr Many many thanks.

Comment: Excuse me, for end comment, what is high order derivative of pw in this code? (For example: D[pw, {t, 3}]).

Comment: I wrote MapAt[D[D[#, x], x] &, 
 Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, x <= 4}}], {{1, ;; , 1}}], but I can not write higher.

Comment: `MapAt[D[#, {x, 2}] &, 
 Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, x <= 4}}], {{1, ;; , 1}}]` gives the second derivative.

Comment: I am very much ashamed,  for this code MapAt[D[#, {x, 2}] &, pw1+pw2+pw3, {{1, ;; , 1}}], I have problem.

Comment: @bahram, you need to use `PiecewiseExpand[pw1 + pw2 + pw3]` or `Simplify[pw1 + pw2 + pw3]` instead of `pw1+pw2+pw3`.

Comment: I can not use Simplify or Expand, because I have pw1*A+pw2*B which are constant.

Comment: `PiecewiseExpand[pw1*A + pw2*B]` and `Simplify[pw1*A + pw2*B]` both work. What are you getting when you use `PiecewiseExpand[pw1*A + pw2*B]`?

Comment: I want D[pw1]+D[pw2]  separate for this code, please:   " Y[x_] = Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, x <= 4}}]*F + 
   Piecewise[{{x^4, 0 <= x <= 3}, {x, x <= 6}}]*G;

MapAt[D[#, {x, 2}] &, Y[x], {{1, ;; , 1}}]"

Comment: @bahram, as is the function `MapAt[...]` is for expressions that have `Head` `Piecewise`. For complicated expressions like your `Y[x]` you can use it to replace `Piecewise` expressions inside `Y[x]` as follows: `Y[x] /. pw_Piecewise :> MapAt[D[#, {x, 2}] &, pw, {{1, ;; , 1}}]`

Answer (score 1):

Using an undocumented function,

```
Piecewise[Transpose[Reverse[MapAt[D[#, x] &, 
          Internal`FromPiecewise[Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, x <= 4}}]], 2]]]]
   Piecewise[{{2 x, 0 <= x <= 1}, {1, x <= 4}}, 0]
```